# How to route the traffic from a specific port through a socks 5 server?

Tags: iptables, firewall, socks

I'm running oracle sql on port 1521. However I can connect on it from a remote server only through a socks5 proxy(due firewall restriction). The client that I use to connect to the sql server doesn't support socks5 so the question is "How to route all the traffic from port 1521 through a socks5 proxy ?"

Comment: You mean "all traffic **to** port 1521"?

Comment: @HaukeLaging no . I mean the traffic that goes from to 1521 to be routed through a socks proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I easily googled http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/ but I never used it, so I can't tell for sure it would satisfy your need.